# Ideas for getting an activeadmin table inside the edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a model called: "UserDashboard".

```
class UserDashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :properties
```

I am using ActiveAdmin. On the edit page I have a combobox where I can choose a user and several checkboxes where I can choose properties.

However, what I really need is having the whole property index with checkboxes (with all its filters).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: did you try to use table_for inside form block?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible by default. You need to hack many many different things to get that working.

Maybe a [belongs_to](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#belongs-to) and a look on [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3691) will help you.